# Search for datum in other Google Sheets tabs and report which tab it was seen in?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet called `MasterList` where every person is assigned an ID#. See example:

[image: 1]

Once a week we check to see who has shown up using their ID#. When the ID# is punched in Column A, their name appears in Column B. See Week1 sheet example:

[image: 2]

In the `MasterList` sheet I would like another column called `Last Seen` which would take that person's name/ID and search the Week1, Week2, Week3... sheets looking for their name/ID. Then, it would report on the `MasterList` when was the last time that person was seen (example: "Week2")

Essentially I am looking to search for a datum in several other Google Sheets tabs, then report on the mastersheet which tab it was seen in. Is there a way to do this efficiently and accurately?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom function and use Google Apps Script's TextFinder class to search the whole spreadsheet.

### Example:

**Code:**

*This code will list all the sheets where the string is found. If the string is found on multiple Sheet, it will return all the sheets name on a space delimited string. **Example:** Sheet1 Sheet2 Sheet3*

```
function lastSeen(identifier) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var finder = ss.createTextFinder(identifier).matchCase(true).findAll();
  var sheetArr = [];
  finder.forEach(find => {
    var sheetName = find.getSheet().getSheetName();
    if ( sheetName != 'MasterList') {  
      sheetArr.push(sheetName);
    }
  })
  return sheetArr.join(" ");  
}
```

**MasterList**

Using Name

[image]

Using ID

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

### Reference:

- [How to create custom function in Google Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [TextFinder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll())